# Python Selenium chromedriver - Action Chain (Control + click) opens url in new window as well as in current window for a non anchor tag

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

There is a div tag which I want to control click using selenium chromedriver. As soon as Action Chain is performed, new tab opens up with the desired link(new url) but this is also triggering a click on current/main window and new url opens in the main window. 
Below is the code:

```
class Scraper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

    def get_last_line_number(self):
        return len(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "gwt-Label") and contains(@class, "WJSO") and contains(@class, "WPTO")]'))

    def get_links(self, max_company_count=15000):
```

self.driver.get('https://ascenaretail.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/us_corporate_jobs')
        self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.WN1N")))

```
    main_window = self.driver.current_window_handle
    last_line_number = 0
    while last_line_number < max_company_count:
        self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        self.wait.until(lambda driver: self.get_last_line_number() != last_line_number)
        last_line_number = self.get_last_line_number()
        all_elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, "WJYF") and contains(@class, "WHYF")]')
        data_array = []
        for element in all_elements:
            title_element = element.find_element_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "gwt-Label") and contains(@class, "WPTO") and contains(@class, "WJSO")]')
            element_text = title_element.text
            location_element = element.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[contains(@class, "gwt-InlineLabel") and contains(@class, "WM-F") and contains(@class, "WLYF")]')
            ActionChains(self.driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(title_element).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
            self.driver.switch_to_window(self.driver.window_handles[1])

            self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.GWTCKEditor-Disabled")))

            print(self.driver.current_url)
            self.driver.switch_to_window(main_window)
            print(self.driver.current_url)
            break
        break    
    return True;

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = Scraper()
    company_links = scraper.get_links(max_company_count=146)
```

The ActionChains is working correct and opening url in new tab but also opening the url in current tab and I am losing control over the tab